# Mongo sort by pattern position

Tags: mongodb, sorting, search, match

Is this possible to sort by pattern position in Mongo?
E.g. lookig for *school*:

1. *school*
2. *school*girl
3. High *school*

Best regards!

Comment: Was that answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a hint.

[Use indexOf](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfBytes/) to find the occurrence position

Then do [conditional sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55159417/mongodb-conditional-sort)

It will sort you the way you want.

Please update the question/open new one with your attempts.